# Regex to match string of characters except for the last four characters and carriage return line feed

Tags: regex

String Example:

- AFN/FMHABX983,.XXXXXX,,155650/FPON43531W078351,0/FCOADS,01/FCOATC,017167^M

I need a regex that will find `/FCOATC,01`

`/FCOATC,` is a fixed match

The values after the comma can be: 01,02,03,1,2,3

`7176` is a CRC value and can be any 4 Alpha Num Characters.

I originally started with this regex `(\/)FCOATC,[^\/|^\n]*` But then realized that I also don't want it to match on the 4 character CRC value. But I'm struggling because the values after the comma can be 1 or 2 characters.

Note: I have the ^/ included because this FCOATC section might be followed by another section that would start with a /. For example:

- AFN/FMHABX983,.XXXXXX,,155650/FPON43531W078351,0/FCOADS,01/FCOATC,01/FCOXYZ,17167^M

So I need it to take each instance into consideration.

**Edited to add the following:**
To break out the /FMH portion I have a dilemma there as well. The breakout for that section is as follows:

```
Fixed Match /FMH 
1-7 alpha numeric characters 
Fixed Match , 
7 [.0-9A-Z-] characters 
Optional Fixed Match , 
Optional 6 characters 
Optional Fixed Match , 
Optional 6 digits
```

All of that could be followed by a / or a 4 character CRC code that would be followed by a carriage return line feed. I want to grab everything listed above, excluding the / or 4 character CRC that could follow.

Examples:
`/FMHABX983,.XXXXXX,,155650/`
`/FMHABX983,.XXXXXX/`
`/FMHAMX022,.XXXXXX,A07176,003555/`
`/FMHAMX022,.XXXXXX,A071761234\r\n`
`/FMHABX983,.XXXXXX1234\r\n`
`/FMHABX983,.XXXXXX,,1556501234\r\n`
`/FMHABX983,.XXXXXX,,1234\r\n`
`/FMHABX983,.XXXXXX,1234\r\n`

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the capture group to what you want to keep, and match an optional zero followed by 1, 2 or 3. Note that if the delimiter of the pattern is not `/` you don't have to escape the forward slash.

```
\/(FCOATC,0?[123])
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cKNGC4/1).

If there should be either 4 digits, or `/` or the end of the string, you could match those using an alternation `|` matching either one of the alternatives:

```
\/(FCOATC,0?[123])(?:\d{4}|\/|$)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cp1euU/1).

**Edit**

You can optionally match all the parts in between, and at the end match either `/` or 4 digits

```
/(FMH[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,7},[.0-9A-Z-]{7},?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{6})?,?(?:\d{6})?)(?:/|\d{4})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A9PCll/1)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I edited my original post with another scenario that perhaps you can help with as well.

Comment: @Christine Do you mean like this? `(FMH[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,7},[.0-9A-Z-]{7},?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{6})?,?(?:\d{6})?)(?:/|\d{4})` https://regex101.com/r/CFUByg/1

Comment: That works perfect! Thank you again for your help :) I know basic regex stuff but I haven't wrapped my head around the more difficult ones yet.